# How can I Automate for selected apps to only use cellular data and not Wi-Fi... and vise versa?

Tags: scripts, automate

I tried doing it myself (On Automate) but it's a bit too advanced. Can I get your help?

Also, I think Android overriding data connection when wifi is on might have to be factored in. I could use Afwall (and Netguard?) to control what connection they use but if the wifi is on, then the app won't be able to use data. For example, on Afwall, I have app x restricted from using Wi-Fi and enabled for it to only us data. But if both WiFi and data connections are on, then the app gets no connection. But if I turn Wi-Fi off, then it will get connected. Turn Wi-Fi back on and no connection again. How do I get around this?

Android 7 | Rooted

Answer (score 2):

1. On the Apps section, select App in foreground? Tap on the block. On the package option, select your app. Press Save.
2. On the Connectivity section, select Wi-Fi set state block. Set the Wi-Fi option to On. Press Save. Link the block to the Yes output of Step 1.
3. On the Connectivity section, select Mobile data set state block. Set the Mobile data option to On. Press Save. Link its input to the No output of Step 1.
4. On the Connectivity section, select Wi-Fi set state block. Set the Wi-Fi option to Off. Press Save. Link its input to the output of Step 3. Then link its output to the input of Step 1
5. Your flow will look like the image below. Give it a name, give the necessary permissions, start the flow.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you so much for that Reddy! Really appreciate it! I'm a little confused. You say the 2nd app. There is no 2nd app. It's just one app that I want to use only cellular data...and everything else on the phone to be as normal (when wifi on...use wifi only). Or should I just disregard creating a flow for another app (unless I decide to late). Could you elaborate please? Thanks again!

Comment: @JJrussel If only one app, then you don't need 2 flows. Enable mobile when the app is on the foreground. Change the No of the App in foreground? block and enable wifi.

Comment: So which one do u go with, 1 or 2? https://imgur.com/0L4orx2

Comment: @JJrussel You will combine part of both. I will edit my answer and change the picture when I have time tomorrow.

Comment: @JJrussel See edit.